# What is NAT port of an IP address?

Tags: networking, debian, ip, nat

I received a request from police to provide all available data of one of the users of my dating website.

So, I sent them IP address, connection times, email address.

Then I got another email with a question if I have registered the NAT port of IP address. What is it? As I understand, it something related to the ISP but how can I register a NAT port of an IP address on a web server with Nginx and Php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to register NAT port with default `nginx` configuration. You should add `$remote_port` to log_format, to log this. More details you could find in [nginx documentation](https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html).

Comment: hmm, thanks. Do you think $remote_port will work with Cloudflare reverse proxy?

Comment: @Verode, I don't know. but according CloudFlare [documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/216672448-Enterprise-Log-Share-Logpull-REST-API), you could get this information from their logs.